# Code splitting in react with respect to serviceworker

Tags: reactjs, service-worker

I have a react application running on example.com/web, which has menus like register, login, and various other pages mainly static which describe what this app is all about. Now once someone logs in I have example.com/app which opens the application, the dashboard, forms, and again many other things related to the application.

I have set different layouts for example.com/web and exapmle.com/app. and when people visit example.com they are auto-redirected to example.com/web

I have implemented lazy loading for /web and /app.

The problem is when someone visits example.com the serviceworker downloads all the files, which may not be required for people visiting the page only to check about the application.

Now I am looking for something where serviceworker downloads only web components and if required then app components. Maybe something like to break this whole react application into two different applications. I can not remove the serviceworker. I'm also not getting any idea what best can be done to reduce the network call. Do let me know what best can be done. I check a few examples on the subdomain and I think it is again a single react app and serviceworker will download all the files.

And if I break it into two different apps how will I pass authenticated props from the login page which is in /web to /app.

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

This question feels a bit like it falls trap to the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If I understand correctly, you are trying to download only the resources you *need* for a route, and you are asking how to do that with a service worker.

However, the problem with service workers is that they are static scripts, and you can only have one active at a time per scope. Therefore it's not really ergonomic to dynamically determine which resources to download within a service worker, and a hacky solution might make it even slower to download.

That being said, it's worth asking yourself why your service worker automatically downloads resources in the first place. Typically that is only done to precache certain resources for offline use. But if a resource isn't meant to be available offline, then it's not useful to precache it, and you should remove it from your service worker's list of files to cache.

By doing so, the browser will otherwise only download the resources that are referenced in your HTML, which are the resources *needed* for the page. And if a critical resource is not immediately referenced in the HTML and is already fetched dynamically, you can use [link preloading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/rel/preload) to hint to the browser to download it slightly ahead of time.

Your service worker can still intercept and cache subsequent requests, but it just doesn't make sense to dynamically precache resources, especially if it's not to use offline. However, if your goal is in fact to precache different resources at different routes for offline use, then you can do so by having 2 service workers registered at different scopes. You can read more about how to use the `scope` option [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerContainer/register), but in essence, your code should look something like this:

```js
// in /web/index.js
if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
  // default scope is /web/
  navigator.serviceWorker.register("/web/service-worker.js")
}

// in /app/index.js
if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
  // default scope is /app/
  navigator.serviceWorker.register("/app/service-worker.js")
}

// in /web/service-worker.js
const PRECACHE_LIST = [
 // items to precache only for routes in /web/
];

// in /app/service-worker.js
const PRECACHE_LIST = [
 // items to precache only for routes in /app/
];
```